# Transferring variables that I got by node.js request (https.get) to another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, request

This will be my first post here, so I'll probably be vague.
I'm trying to get the data via node.js request and then pass them to another js file so that the appropriate html file can use them.
Folder with this app looks like below:

```
-App
 -node_modules
 -public
  -css
    -styles.css
  -js
    -currentWeather.js
 -app.js
 -currentWeather.html
 -index.html
 -package.json e.t.c
```

In app.js i wrote:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.get("/",(req,res) => {

  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");

});
app.post("/", (req,res) =>{

  const city = req.body.city;

  const url = .....

  https.get(url, (response) => {

    response.on("data", (data) => {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      
      // and here somehow i want to export variable city and weatherData and send them to this currentWeather.js in public folder because i want to do DOM manipulation and some styling (currentWeather.html) with the data i got.


      // res.sendFile(__dirname + "/currentWeather.html");
    })
  })
})




app.listen(3000, () => {console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");});
```

And how to get them in this file? - currentWeather.js

Comment: You have to use promises, I will explain.

Comment: You are doing an async operation calling https.get and response.on. You need to handle that using either promises or async/await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use promises to wait for callbacks to finish. For example:

```js
const https = require('https');
let result = await new Promise(resolve =>
    require('https').get('https://www.example.com',res => res.on('data',resolve))
);
console.log(result.toString());
```

Just make sure that it is inside an `async` function:

```
(async()=>{
    // Do stuff
})()
```

Comment: I get it. Can you tell me how to transfer the data that I got in the app.js file to currentWeather.js?

Comment: @Markiz You might want to ask another question for that but the way that you do that is with `require('./js/currentWeather.js')` inside app.js and `module.exports = function() { stuff }`in currentWeather.js. Make sure that the "stuff" is replaced with the function you have above that is edited to use promises.